# read file name from text file in ksh and compress

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I want to write a KornShell (ksh) script to read filename from a textfile(having list of prefixes) and compress it if it is found in the directory by looping.

ex: I will keep the prefix  'abcd' in the text file .

By reading it, I want to compress the files in the directory matching the name like this abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt

I do not want to do anything with same prefix but with different extensions or different patterns like abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.dat or abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt.Z. I only want to compress matching like this abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt only.

How to implement this in ksh?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Note that it is a good idea to be explicit about what you mean by the symbols in your file name templates. In particular, it is not clear what the `X` might be intended to mean. It could be 'anything', or 'any letter' or 'any upper-case letter'.  It also would not hurt to specify which compress program you plan to use.

Answer (score 2):

Superficially, this should do:

```
: ${COMPRESS:=xz}
while read prefix
do
    $COMPRESS ${prefix}[0-9][0-9][0-9].[12][09][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]??????.txt
done < file
```

Obviously, I'm having to make some guesses, that `#` means a digit, that the `YYYYMMDD` is a date, and that `X` is any character (that's `?` in the answer). If `X` is meant to be any upper-case alphabetic, or something else, adjust accordingly.  The year rules will accept 19xx and 20xx (also 10xx and 29xx, but you're unlikely to have files dated like that; the month rules accept 00..19; the day rules accept 00..39.  If you have to validate more, then you can't readily use a simple globbing regex.

I used `xz` as the compress program.  I would not use the `compress` program for compression as it simply doesn't compare with `gzip`, let alone `bzip2` or `xz`, etc.